# Weird multithreading behavior - CompilerExplorer link

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, std, compiler-explorer

**TL;DR:** Why does this https://godbolt.org/z/ohK31hW34 multithreaded program  segfault?

**Explanation:** I am encountering weird behavior of my multithreaded C++ application. The application has multiple threads that loop in a while loop guarded by an `std::atomic<bool>` variable. I use this construct in multiple places, so I extracted it to a simple `ThreadLoop` class with `Start(function)` & `Stop()` methods.

```
class ThreadLoop
{
public:
  ThreadLoop(const std::string& name) : mName(name) {}
  ~ThreadLoop() { Stop(); }

  template <typename F>
  void Start(F&& function)
  {
    if (mRunning)
      return;

    std::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
    if (mThread.joinable())
      mThread.join();

    mRunning = true;
    mThread = std::thread([&]() {
      while (mRunning)
      {
        function();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
      }
    });
  }

  void Stop()
  {
    if (not mRunning)
      return;

    mRunning = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }

private:
  std::atomic<bool> mRunning = false;
  std::mutex mMutex;
  std::thread mThread;
  std::string mName;
};
```

I then use an object of this custom class as a member in a different 'worker' class that assigns a particular function to be periodically executed, like so

```
class Worker1
{
public:
  void StartWorking()
  {
    mThread.Start([this]() { Work(); });
  }

  void StopWorking() { mThread.Stop(); }

private:
  ThreadLoop mThread{"worker1 loop"};

  void Work()
  {
    fmt::print("Working...\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
  }
};
```

I have all of these 'workers' in another class and call `StartWorking()` / `StopWorking()` on them at random time points (also in a `ThreadLoop`)

```
class Main
{
public:
  void Start()
  {
    mThread.Start([this]() { MainLoop(); });
  }

  void Stop() { mThread.Stop(); }

private:
  ThreadLoop mThread{"main loop"};
  Worker1 mWorker1;

  void MainLoop()
  {
    if (/*something*/)
      mWorker1.StartWorking();
    else
      mWorker1.StopWorking();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
  }
};
```

The first `ThreadLoop` ("main loop") in the `Main` class starts fine and starts calling `StartWorking()` / `StopWorking()`, as expected. The `StartWorking()` then triggers the worker to start its own `ThreadLoop` ("worker1 loop"), which fails undeterministically inside the `ThreadLoop::Start()` function, for example via

```
    `../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:81: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion mutex->__data.__owner == 0 failed`
```

Also, according to the debugger, the entire `ThreadLoop` object seems to be uninitialized / destroyed (e.g. the `std::string mName` variable is empty, although I always provide a non-empty string) - this probably causes the `std::scoped_lock` to fail - locking an uninitialized/destroyed mutex. My question is, how/why is the `ThreadLoop` object uninitialized? I think I clearly construct it as a member inside each `Worker1` object?

Comment: Is there code somewhere that calls `Stop()` on your `Main` object before the `Main` object is destroyed?  If not, that could cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks for the tip. I dont think that's it - the program crashes immediately after the "inner" Start() is called. Also, Stop() is called in the ThreadLoop destructor, so that should be fine, at least I think.

Comment: If I was debugging this, the first thing I would do is implement destructors for each of the classes involved, and (temporarily) add `cout << "Destructor called for class X" << endl;` type debug-prints into each destructor.  That way I could see for myself if (and when) each object was getting destroyed, and that would help me understand why/when/how it was getting into the problematic/destroyed state.

Comment: Note that calling `Stop` in the `ThreadLoop` destructor doesn't help you much if the `Worker` is destroyed before the `ThreadLoop` is destroyed (which, from the posted code, appears to be the case -- member-variables are destroyed in the opposite order from the order which they are initialized, and member-variables declared first in the containing class are initialized before member-variables declared later in the containing class)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner good ideas. But I still wonder why anything gets destroyed at all - to my eyes there's no place where things should get destroyed, except at the end of main(), but I crash much earlier than that.

Comment: @Jixxy if things are in fact getting destroyed, putting a call to `abort()` into the relevant destructor should pop you right into the debugger where you can get a nice stack trace that will show you where and how the destruction occurred.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I added a Godbolt link that reproduces the problem

Comment: I can reproduce the crash on my machine -- I notice that if I put a `printf("this=%p\n", this);` just before the call to `Work()` inside the lambda inside `mThread.Start()`, it prints out `this=0x0`.  I think the rest of your problems stem from that, but I don't understand lambdas well enough to understand why the value of the captured `this` argument isn't preserved inside the lambda-callback.

Comment: Ok now that is super weird. Also, I noticed that if I compile my code in release mode, it works. .. what?

Comment: Smells like undefined behavior to me :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was capturing the `T&& function` by reference in the lambda inside `ThreadLoop::Start()`, and the thread then invoked the lambda, which was a dangling reference. The fix was to capture `T&& function` **by value**.

Original version:

```
mThread = std::thread([&](){ ... })
```

Fixed version:

```
mThread = std::thread([this, function](){ ... })
```

Even better version:

```
mThread = std::jthread([this, function](){ ... })
```